# Unable to use certain socket.io functions after redirecting page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I'm working on a multiplayer game that uses socket.io to handle server-client code. Part of my game requires the user to be redirected to another page. Although this all works perfectly fine, after redirecting the clients in a room to a different html page, they don't receive anything when I call the function `io.in(roomname).emit(something)`. Although I can still communicate with each individual socket, I can no longer send data to every client in a room. Is there any way to get around this?

Initializations:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

var gameID = process.env.PORT || 2000;
var players = {}; // a dictionary that stores a list of player objects (which stores their name and socket id) for each room
```

Redirecting the clients:

```js
socket.on('redirect me to the game', function(){
    var destination = '/game.html';
    io.in(playerRoomName).emit('redirect', destination);
});
```

Since I store all of the player data in a dictionary with a list of player objects per room, when the sockets disconnect and new sockets connect after I redirect the clients, I modify the player dictionary by adjusting their socket ids to the new ones.

```js
socket.on('sending identity', function(data) {
    console.log('Room ' + data.room + ': received identity from ' + data.name);
    playerRoomName = data.room;
    var playerName = data.name;
    console.log(players[playerRoomName]);
    console.log(data);
    thisPlayer = new Player(playerName, socket.id, playerRoomName);
    players[playerRoomName].push(thisPlayer);
  });
```

The order: The first thing I do in the server script is the initializations. Then, I have my server code that manages connections and disconnections from sockets. When the sockets connect to a room, I store their information as a player object and add them as players in my player dictionary. When they disconnect, I remove them. However, after there are enough players and one of them starts the game, I redirect all of the players to the game.html file which is stored in my client folder just like my index.html file is. My game.html file has a script attached to it that initializes a socket and connects to the server, sending it the name of the player and the room the player was in. This way, in the server script, I can update the player dictionary with the new socket id. At this point, my clients no longer receive anything when I call `io.in(roomname).emit()`;

Comment: Impossible to help without some relevant code.

Comment: @i.brod, Thanks for letting me know. I just added all the code I thought was relevant.

Comment: This redirecting, takes the player to a new static HTML page, or is it just a route in a single page app, like React? What is your frontend environment? If it's a new HTML page, all the javascript you had in the previous one will become irrelevant, including the socketio stuff.

Comment: It's a new static HTML page, and I have another script attached to that page that initializes a new socket and handles client-side code after the redirect.

Comment: The flow here is not clear to me...the order is very important

Comment: Ok, I just added the order of everything I do to the question